# Swing, при повторном открытии окна не четкое отображение

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте, я только учу swing, и столкнулся с проблемой,есть приложение,в котором нажимаешь на кнопку и открывается окно с регистрацией.При первом нажатии на кнопку,окно отображается корректно.при следующих нажатиях выводится это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
public class MyButton1 implements ActionListener {
        JFrame frame32 = new JFrame();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String s = login.getText();
            String s1 = password.getText();
            try {
                if (s.isEmpty() || s1.isEmpty()) {
                } else {
                    statement.executeUpdate(
                            "insert into table(login,password)values('" + s + "','" + s1 + "')");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
            }
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
            russ.setText("");
            eng.setText("");
        }

    }
public class MyButton implements ActionListener {
    public JTextField login = new JTextField(15);
    public JTextField password = new JTextField(15);
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("Login");
        JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel("Password");

        JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Ok");
        button.addActionListener(new MyButton1());
        jPanel.add(jLabel);
        jPanel.add(login);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
        jPanel1.add(password);
        frame.add(jPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(jPanel1, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();

    }
```

окно закрывается при нажатии на кнопку Ок, код выше это закрытие этого окна.
Подскажите из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: а если нечеткое окно сминизировать и снова открыть оно тогда четкое?

Comment: @plesser нет,помогает только полное закрытие приложение.

Comment: И еще вопрос, а зачем ты открываешь его как фрейм? Почему не как диалоговое окно?

Comment: руками repaint() пробовал добавлять после открытия?

Comment: @Tachkin попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: @plesser незнаю,сделал как умел)

Comment: @plesser в данном случае лучше создавать диалоговое окно?

Comment: Добавь код формирования формы в вопрос

Comment: @Tachkin добавил

Comment: Да, так идеологически более правильно будет

Comment: Я могу ошибаться (давно swing использовал) но вроде setVisible самое последнее должно быть

Comment: @plesser спасибо,буду теперь создавать диалоговые окна.
setVisible переставил,но ситуация не поменялась.

Comment: попробуй формирование формы вынести из метода слушателя actionPerformed в класс , а то получается, что при каждом отображении формы ты на нее добавляешь кучу всего.

Comment: @Tachkin спасибо большое,сделал как Вы сказали и теперь проблема исчезла!